# Which frame_id do I usually specify for the NavSatFix header?

Tags: ros, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coordinate system in NavSatFix is known by the fact that we are using WSG84 coordinates. But how do I specify the frame_id in the header? Is there some standard name for this frame, or will it be different in every project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210124/which-frame_id-do-i-usually-specify-for-the-navsatfix-header?/) by [DanielEckert](https://answers.ros.org/users/22166/danieleckert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This came up recently in a [drivers sig discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-drivers/va4F_EUF0CY). The question I asked was that if sensor is measuring pose data in some world-referenced frame, but is mounted on the robot with some static offset (transform) from the vehicle's origin, what should we put in the `frame_id` field of the message? In this case, @mikepurvis pointed out that the [NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) message indicates what is expected. You should put in the `frame_id` in which the sensor is mounted (the transform from *base_link*).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i guess it depends where your gps antenna is mounted on your robot....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1